# Admin panel for Rails app using Riak?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, riak

I am trying to migrate a Rails app from MySQL to Riak (with Ripple), and have not been able to find a drop-in (or close to it) admin-panel that is Riak-compatible (or close to it).  Do you know of any, or any way to modify an extant Rails admin-panel to add Ripple support, or anything else that might help?

I have tried Active Admin, Rails Admin, and Typus, looked briefly at Admin Data, and Googled '(riak OR ripple) (rails OR rubyonrails) "admin panel"' (sans outer quotes) but did not see anything that looked useful.  There were only two things that looked at all promising.  First is that I had made a little bit of headway (i.e., did not run into totally insurmountable problems yet) shoehorning some Ripple support into Rails Admin, but even that looked like more trouble than it was worth... especially given that I'm also brand-new to Riak!  (And fairly new to the whole NoSQL thing.)  Second was riak_control.  However, that seems to be for controlling the whole Riak setup.  The UI snapshots in the docs do indeed show a button for an an Objects tab.  However, further investigation reveals that the Objects section is not yet implemented and the button has been removed.

Thank you for any light you can shed!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it on riak 1.4 but I use rekon to browse and edit my riak nodes.  You can check it out at: https://github.com/adamhunter/rekon